# Time Issue in JS React Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Is there any way to get global time of a timezone instead of relying on user computer time. Like for example if i need current time which is for example 12:30 PM but user pc time is behind so i get that behind time instead of 12:30

Comment: You can use an API, for example [Google timezone's API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview#examples). You can find [at the bottom of the website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview#calculating-time) how to calculate the time

Comment: thanx its just giving me timezone name i want actual time can u paste the link for it

Comment: You can find [at the bottom of the website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview#calculating-time) how to calculate the time

Answer (score 0):

fetch("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata")
res below

```
{
    "abbreviation": "IST",
    "client_ip": "2409:4064:88f:cbb9:7477:697e:bf20:b2eb",
    "datetime": "2021-09-04T15:07:49.219998+05:30",
    "day_of_week": 6,
    "day_of_year": 247,
    "dst": false,
    "dst_from": null,
    "dst_offset": 0,
    "dst_until": null,
    "raw_offset": 19800,
    "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "unixtime": 1630748269,
    "utc_datetime": "2021-09-04T09:37:49.219998+00:00",
    "utc_offset": "+05:30",
    "week_number": 35
    }


var date = new Date(unixtime * 1000);
var h = date.getHours();
var m = "0" + date.getMinutes();
var s = "0" + date.getSeconds();
var formattedTime = h + ':' + m.substr(-2) + ':' + s.substr(-2);
console.log(formattedTime); // 15:07:49
```

Comment: hope you got the solution

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.